# Can "actually" be used in narration?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Well technically, it can, but would it be bad to use it in narration in the context of:

> After loading his gun, he aimed at the bird, and he pulled the trigger. With a bang, the bullet flew through the air, and a dark shadow could be seen falling down from the air. He actually shot the bird from a thousand meters away!

The "actually" in that context implies "unexpectedness". However, for some reason (no idea why), it sound...*off*. In fact, I think I would prefer to remove the "actually" from the paragraph above, making it:

> After loading his gun, he aimed at the bird, and he pulled the trigger. With a bang, the bullet flew through the air, and a dark shadow could be seen falling down from the air. He shot the bird from a thousand meters away!

I think the second one sounds a bit better, and even with "actually", the unexpectedness is already there.

So, questions: 1) Which example is better? 2) Is the first example "proper", grammatically wise? 3) Is "actually", in terms of "unexpectedness", should only be used in conversations and not narration?

Comment: Could you add a dictionary reference where you found *actually* to mean "unexpectedness"?

Comment: @user3169 It doesn't particularly _mean_ "unexpectedness", but it somewhat implies it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After loading his gun, he aimed at the bird, and he pulled the trigger. With a bang, the bullet flew through the air, and a dark shadow could be seen falling down from the air. He actually shot the bird from a thousand meters away!

*Actually* is fine here, either in conversation or narration.

*Actually* is not required, so there is no "better", just which one do you prefer? Often, such adverbs add little to the meaning and so they can be dropped.

If I had to make a change, I might change the last sentence to

> He **had** (actually) shot the bird from a thousand meters away!

I would do this mostly because this sentence is not really an action that takes place in your narrative but a statement regarding the past actions (involved in shooting the bird).

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the answer, and your change (the had) was also what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This answer does not address the concern "*actually* in that context implies *unexpectedness*".

Comment: No, but you might not find this sense in your dictionarry. To add "actually" in emphasis of something clearly stated as factual, is to refute the unheard (but anticipated) objection "really? That's unbelievable!"